# Strange yellow flower in shrub Species ID

Tags: species-identification, botany, flowers

This is a perennial plant photo taken in Bhubaneswar, Odisha, but I have seen the same plant in Andhra Pradesh as well. It's not exactly woody like a tree, but pretty large shrub [taller than me].
[image]
[image]

What species is it?

Comment: Anything else you can tell us about the plant - the shape/form/habit? is the plant woody or soft? If you are searching include the terms pinnate leaves, flower raceme/racemic

Answer (score 5):

Looks like a type of legume called a [**senna**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Senna_(plant)), though I do not know for certain which species -- see below for a pretty good guess!

Things that stand out about your specimen: most prominent are the erect/many-flowered yellow [inflorescences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inflorescence), which are called [racemes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raceme). You can see narrow green seed pods below your inflorescences as well -- these appear to be *winged*. Also noteworthy are the [pinnately compound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leaf#Divisions_of_the_blade) leaves with [opposite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leaf#Arrangement_on_the_stem) leaflets having [emarginate](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/emarginate) tips and [entire](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leaf#Edge_(margin)) margins -- I count 18-22 leaflets on leaves in your second image.

One such species that matches your specimen pretty well is [***Senna alata***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Senna_alata), the **candelabra bush**.

[image: Senna alata plant]

<sup>Credit: Marie Lacouture ; Source: [TRAMIL Library](https://www.tramil.net/en/plant/senna-alata)</sup>

- This is a shrub-like plant growing 3-4 m tall, has bright yellow racemes that open bottom to top in the fall, leaves with 18-28 entire leaflets that can sometimes have emarginate tips, and is in-fact named for its *winged* seedpods (*ala* = winged).

Although native to the Neotropics, [iNaturalist](https://guatemala.inaturalist.org/taxa/81515-Senna-alata#map-tab) shows *many* observations of this plant in India.

Other Sources:

- [Missouri Botanical Garden](https://www.missouribotanicalgarden.org/PlantFinder/PlantFinderDetails.aspx?kempercode=a495)
- [N Parks (Singapore)](https://www.nparks.gov.sg/florafaunaweb/flora/2/4/2450)
- [Weeds of Australia](https://keyserver.lucidcentral.org/weeds/data/media/Html/senna_alata.htm)